# iron router: is it a good idea to subscribe a collection in onBeforeAction?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Iron router provides a mechanism to wait till a subscription is ready using "subscription" or "waitOn". But the page doesn't get rendered until the subscription is ready.

In my case, I have some large collections that may take some time to subscribe. It may not be a good idea to wait before showing anything (especially it is the home page). Thus, I tried to put the subscribe function call inside onBeforeAction hook, and it works fine. The subscription doesn't return any data initially, and then when the data arrives it gets reactively run again. This way, the page would display something at first and then some portions of the page get filled later with real content.

I don't see this method been discussed before. So I wonder whether this is a decent way to reduce the perceived response time at the cost of re-computation. Any draw back in this method?

One thing I can think of is that if I put some code in Template.name.rendered that depends on the data, it may not behave correctly, as the rendered function is only executed once. It actually caused some issues for me and I have another question asking about that: [Meteor, where to put d3 code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924253/meteor-where-to-put-d3-code)

Any other issues besides the one I identified?

Comment: Maybe you should subscribe to a smaller publication like only _id's and then get more data with a template helper and a server method. I use both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the Subscriptions Manager for Meteor :
https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager
It's supposed to let you cache some subs to be more responsive.
Did you try to use kadira to trace more your subscriptions ?

Comment: I use subscription manager. But the page I want to use is the home page, so it doesn't help here. I also use kadira a bit.