# Iron-Router Does NOT Render Template A Second Time For Data Change Context in same Route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a route using iron-router as described below:

```
//// Preview ROUTE
Router.route('/preview/:_id', {
  template:'preview',
  subscriptions: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('files', 'preview', currentIncident());
},
data: function () {
    return Files.findOne(this.params._id);
},
action: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
        this.render();
    } else {
        this.render("loading");
    }
},
onAfterAction: function() {
    // always start by resetting scroll to top of the page
    $(window).scrollTop(0);

}
```

});

The `Template.preview.rendered` only gets called when I come from a different route, i.e `/home`.  However if I use `Router.go("/preview/someID")` from a `/preview/differentID` the `Template.preview.rendered` does not get called. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the `rendered` block? Please share `Template.preview.rendered` code

Comment: @Rajanand02 I have a `d3` chart that needs to be redrawn with the new file data context passed in from `iron-router`. I can achieve the functionality of the redraw in a another way but it seems doing it through the `template.rendered` would be the cleanest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor, where to put d3 code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924253/meteor-where-to-put-d3-code)