# Counter-Up not increasing int in Meteor application

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using the [Counter-Up](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up) plugin for my Meteor application.
On first site load it works fine, but there seems to be a problem with real-time changes.

I want to display total games created in my web app, so I have this helper:

```
totalGames: function () {
     return Games.find().count();
}
```

and this is my rendered function:

```
Template.home.rendered = function () {
    $('.counter').counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 500
    });
};
```

Now the problem is, the counter does not increase, due to the reactivity. So if user A sees the counter with the number **1** on the home site and suddenly a new game is created, the number changes to **12** and not **2**.

How can I solve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Template.home.rendered = function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    if (Template.currentData() && Games.find().count())
      $('.counter').counterUp({delay: 10, time: 500});
  });
};
```

In theory, this should rerun the `counterUp` initialization any time the `Games` count changes. The `Template.currentData` business is just a hack to make the the `autorun` work inside of `rendered` - see my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924253/meteor-where-to-put-d3-code).

Answer (score 0):

When I get this behavior I run this. I've also run into issues with randomness. The delay is caused by the minimongo which sits on your browser not getting the correct cache from mongodb.

Here are things that I do to kick start the ddp to get the data through the wire.

1) I close out of the terminal. This should have 0 affect, but sometimes things get hung up. Just Try it.

2) rm -rf ~/[name of project].meteor/local/.mirror

3) double check I saved my changes.